# Psalm error for TwigFilter callable parameter

Tags: php, symfony, twig, psalm-php

I get this error from psalm for a twig extension:

> ERROR: InvalidArgument - src/Twig/CartExtension.php:44:17 - Argument 2
> of Twig\TwigFilter::__construct expects callable|null,
> array{App\Twig\CartExtension&static, string(getOfferDate)} provided

The code in question is:

```
public function getFilters(): array
{
    return [
        new TwigFilter(
            'get_offer_date',
            [$this, 'getOfferDate']
        ),
    ];
}
```

And the TwigFilter signature is

```
/**
 * @param callable|null $callable A callable implementing the filter. If null, you need to overwrite the "node_class" option to customize compilation.
 */
public function __construct(string $name, $callable = null, array $options = [])

...
```

The twig docs recommend this format

> [$this, 'getOfferDate']

for the callable: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

How can i fix this psalm error or tell psalm to accept it?

Comment: Seems you can suppress certain errors for specific files. See [here](https://psalm.dev/docs/running_psalm/dealing_with_code_issues/)

Comment: Do you have method `getOfferDate` created in same class?

Comment: @Leprechaun thats exactly the problem. Feel free to post this as answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `getOfferDate()` should be created inside of class. In your case, inside of class `CartExtension`.